# What is the equivalent command to powershell's New-SelfSignedCertificate in Redhat?

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, redhat

I need to create a certificate and use it from both my machine and Azure's app registration  to allow my machine to authenticate with Azure Active Directory in order to get access to the secrets in the azure KeyVault.

When I was using windows, I use to do it like this:
`New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=MyCertificate" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature`

But now when I want to port my app to Redhdat Linux, I'm confused how to do it and where the certificate gets stored.

Is there a specific command or library that does it?

Answer (score 0):

To create a self-signed certificate on Red Hat Linux for use with Azure Active Directory and Azure Key Vault, you can use OpenSSL, a widely-used tool for managing SSL/TLS certificates.
Generate a 2048-bit RSA private key using OpenSSL:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048
```

[image]

Create a certificate signing request (CSR) and then generate a self-signed certificate:

```
 openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mycsr.csr -subj "/CN=MyCertificate"
```

```bash
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mycsr.csr -signkey mykey.key -out mycert.crt
```

[image]

This produces a one-year-valid certificate named `mycert.crt`.
Azure requires the certificate in PKCS#12 (`.pfx` or `.p12`) format. Combine your certificate and key:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey mykey.key -in mycert.crt
[image]

set your password and remember the password you set for this file.
Upload your `.pfx` file to Azure:
two ways are there-

*Via Azure Portal:* In your App Registration, under "Certificates & secrets," upload the `certificate.pfx`.
[image]
*Via Azure CLI:* Use the Azure CLI to upload:

```
az ad app credential reset --id <your-app-id> --cert @certificate.pfx --append
```

Linux systems don't have a unified certificate store like Windows. Store your certificate and key in a secure directory, typically:

- Certificates: `/etc/ssl/certs`
- Private keys: `/etc/ssl/private`

[image]
Set appropriate permissions for the private key:

```
sudo chown root:root mykey.key
sudo chmod 600 mykey.key
```

In your application, reference the paths to the certificate and key as required for authentication with Azure.

Reference Document:

[Generate Self Signed Cert using openssl](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/166370/how-to-create-a-selfsigned-ssl-certifica.html)

[generate Self Signed Cert by Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/system_administration_guide/apache_http_secure_server_configuration-generating_a_key)

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps)